# jboss & maven: maven build fails due to libraries not opening

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I am building the jboss EA 6.3 quickstart project "greeter".

I run `maven clean install jboss-as:deploy` in the project dir as instructed whilist a jboss server is running.

I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.
1:compile (default-compile) on project jboss-greeter: Compilation failure: Compi
lation failure:
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\boris\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\faces\j
boss-jsf-api_2.1_spec\2.1.28.Final-redhat-1\jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-
redhat-1.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\boris\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persiste
nce\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final-redhat-2\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final
-redhat-2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\boris\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transac
tion\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final-redhat-2\jboss-transaction-api_1
.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\boris\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ejb\jbo
ss-ejb-api_3.1_spec\1.0.2.Final-redhat-2\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.2.Final-redh
at-2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\boris\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\faces\j
boss-jsf-api_2.1_spec\2.1.28.Final-redhat-1\jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.1.28.Final-
redhat-1.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\boris\.m2\repository\org\hibernate\javax\persiste
nce\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api\1.0.1.Final-redhat-2\hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final
-redhat-2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\boris\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\transac
tion\jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec\1.0.1.Final-redhat-2\jboss-transaction-api_1
.1_spec-1.0.1.Final-redhat-2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\boris\.m2\repository\org\jboss\spec\javax\ejb\jbo
ss-ejb-api_3.1_spec\1.0.2.Final-redhat-2\jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.2.Final-redh
at-2.jar; error in opening zip file
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/Resources.java:[24,27] packag
e javax.faces.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/Resources.java:[44,12] cannot
 find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FacesContext
[ERROR] location: class org.jboss.as.quickstarts.greeter.Resources
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/web/CreateController.java:[21
,31] package javax.faces.application does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/web/CreateController.java:[22
,27] package javax.faces.context does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/web/CreateController.java:[34
,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FacesContext
[ERROR] location: class org.jboss.as.quickstarts.greeter.web.CreateController
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/domain/ManagedBeanUserDao.jav
a:[23,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SystemException
[ERROR] location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/domain/ManagedBeanUserDao.jav
a:[24,25] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class UserTransaction
[ERROR] location: package javax.transaction
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/domain/ManagedBeanUserDao.jav
a:[32,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class UserTransaction
[ERROR] location: class org.jboss.as.quickstarts.greeter.domain.ManagedBeanUserD
ao
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/domain/EJBUserDao.java:[19,17
] package javax.ejb does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/domain/EJBUserDao.java:[26,2]
 cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol: class Stateful
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/Resources.java:[45,16] cannot
 find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable FacesContext
[ERROR] location: class org.jboss.as.quickstarts.greeter.Resources
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/web/CreateController.java:[48
,47] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FacesMessage
[ERROR] location: class org.jboss.as.quickstarts.greeter.web.CreateController
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/web/CreateController.java:[51
,47] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class FacesMessage
[ERROR] location: class org.jboss.as.quickstarts.greeter.web.CreateController
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/domain/ManagedBeanUserDao.jav
a:[50,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SystemException
[ERROR] location: class org.jboss.as.quickstarts.greeter.domain.ManagedBeanUserD
ao
[ERROR] /C:/Users/boris/Desktop/JavaLearning/jboss-eap-quickstarts-6.3.0.GA/gree
ter/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/quickstarts/greeter/domain/ManagedBeanUserDao.jav
a:[68,22] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class SystemException
[ERROR] location: class org.jboss.as.quickstarts.greeter.domain.ManagedBeanUserD
ao
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit
ch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please rea
d the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureExc
eption
```

I checked the files it tries to open in the maven repo. They all are 1kb large and won't open by winrar. Windows says "file corrupt or damaged".

Other examples (without JSF though) worked just fine.

Comment: Your Maven repo location is not the same as your Maven home.

Comment: Looks like bogus dependencies somewhere/somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the specified files that maven couldn't open. Maven redownloaded them, then it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

What is your M2_HOME?  You can configure the path in the M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml, e.g.:

```
<!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ${user.home}/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->
```

Comment: I took the settings.xml from the quickstarts and overwritten the original settings.xml with it as instructed. It has no fragment like the one you showed.

Comment: You can also purge your repository:  https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/purging-local-repository.html